# How to remove/disconnect an Azure VNET from an Azure Service App Plan?

Tags: azure, vnet

I'm trying to remove/disconnect a VNET (which doesn't exist any more) from an existing App Service Plan.

Here's some screen shots showing what I have:

[image]

So here it's saying that the Classic VNET doesn't exist any more. This is true. It was migrated to ARM so it's renamed/etc.

So let's click on that vnet name to see what that VNET sync details are:

[image]

Okay - this is interesting. It correctly says the VNET doesn't exist. Good.

But then it says: `DISCONNECT BUTTON ABOVE` .. which I want to click/use .. but it doesn't exist.

So how can I remove/disconnect this "not found" VNET from this App Service Plan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To **disconnect** VNET from App Service plan, you need to do it from **`App Service`** not App Service plan.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I deleted the existing **classic** virtual network that is integrated to my App Service.

When I checked the **status** of it in App Service plan, it is showing  `Not found` same as you like below:

[image]

When I clicked that VNET name, I got the screen with **same details** as you like below:

[image]

As it says, you can remove the VNET from **App Service** using `Disconnect` button like below:

***Go to Azure Portal -> App Services -> Your App Service -> Networking -> VNet Integration -> Disconnect***

[image]

When I clicked on **Disconnect**, I got the screen like below:

[image]

After selecting **Yes**, VNET removed successfully like below:

[image]